# GitPython : git push - set upstream

Tags: python, gitlab, gitpython

Im using GitPython to clone a master branch and do a checkout of a feature branch, I do my local updates, commit and push back to git. The code snippet looks like below,

Note : my branch name is feature/pythontest

```
def git_clone():
    repo = Repo.clone_from(<git-repo>, <local-repo>)
    repo.git.checkout("-b", "feature/pythontest")
    # I have done with file updates 
    repo.git.add(update=True)
    repo.index.commit("commit")
    origin = repo.remote(name="origin")
    origin.push()
```

When I execute the script, I get the below error,

```
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
git push --set-upstream origin feature/pythontest
```

Answer (score 3):

For pushing new branches you need to run `git push --set-upstream origin branch_name`  you can read on --set-upstream in git documentation https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push
This should do the work for gitpython:

```
def git_clone():
    branch_name = "feature/pythontest"
    repo = Repo.clone_from(<git-repo>, <local-repo>)
    repo.git.checkout("-b", branch_name)
    repo.git.add(repo.working_dir)
    commit_output = repo.git.commit(m="Commit msg")
    push_output = repo.git.push('--set-upstream', repo.remote().name, branch_name)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

`origin.push()` doesn't know how to match the local branch to the one in the origin, so you need to specify it through refspec:

> `origin.push(refspec="master:origin")`

master is your local branch and origin the target.

You can find more details [here](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html) in the fetch definition.

Comment: I think you'd normally want `refspec="master:master"` if you've got a local master branch and you want it to track the master branch on the remote called 'origin'. (when I did `master:origin` I ended up with my 'origin' remote having a branch also called 'origin' which was tracked by my local branch called 'master')